Is there a Windows 11 app that allows me to share another device's screen onto my PC?
I am using a Windows 11 PC, and I want to be able to connect my Wii U, NES Mini, and Mini Sega Genesis to my computer, but the HDMI on my machine is an output port, not an input. In other words, my Wii U cannot share its screen to my PC.
Is there some software I can use to share the screen from these devices onto my computer? I'll ask a follow up question in StackExchange: Hardware Recommendations if any software needs another hardware device, cord, or extension I need.

Welcome Alex! I'm almost positive you'll need some hardware too, so glad to see you will post a corresponding Hardware Recommendations SE question as well.

The question belongs on Hardware recommendations.  You cant use software to switch your display HDMI port into an input.

@RohitGupta Well, I understand that the HDMI issue is for hardware recommendations, that is why I asked for Software that can help with this. Are there really no software that allows this (even through a different cord)?

No. How do you imagine that working? You are just looking for a HDMI capture card, not even worth asking on hardware recs IMO, lots of advices you can find all over the web.
